# make electron execute itself in run version (npx electron .)

Tags: electron

my app create another instance with some parameters:

```js
exec(remote.process.argv[0] + " " + parameter)
```

In build version, it works perfect.

In dev version (`npx electron .`), it doesn't work.

So I need to re-build everytime.

How can I make my code work in dev version?

---

In dev version:

```js
> remote.process.argv[0]
< "C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\node\editor3\node_modules\electron\dist\electron.exe"
```

It seems it doesn't run my app in dev version.
It just opens a default (empty) electron and put my `parameter` inside it without loading my app (`index.html`).

---

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "editor",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "markd": "^1.2.0",
    "marked": "^0.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^8.2.1",
    "electron-packager": "^14.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "build": "electron-packager ."
  }
}
```

```bash
$ npm -v
6.4.1
$ node -v
v10.15.3
```

Comment: Your npm version and node version please

Comment: Can you attach your package.json?